# Error when installing dmgbuild with pip.

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

I am trying to install dmgbuild with pip and I receive the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

- Windows 10
- Command Prompt (Admin)
- pip version 9.0.1

  C:>pip install dmgbuild
  Collecting dmgbuild
  Using cached dmgbuild-1.3.0.tar.gz
  Collecting ds_store>=1.1.0 (from dmgbuild)
  Using cached ds_store-1.1.0.tar.gz
  Collecting mac_alias>=2.0.1 (from dmgbuild)
  Using cached mac_alias-2.0.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\rpanczer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gvy3qj3a\mac-alias\setup.py", line 5, in 
  longdesc = f.read().decode('utf-8')
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

  ```
  ----------------------------------------
  ```

  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rpanczer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gvy3qj3a\mac-alias\

Answer (score 1):

`str.decode` no longer exists in python 3.x

The error is due to `mac_alias`, which `dmgbuild` depends on,is not compatible to python 3 somehow.

You can check out `mac_alias` homepage.

I just tested everything is okay if you are using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify your python interpreter firstly before writing commands, this may help you in the case you have more than one version installed.

```
C:\ python3 pip install dmgbuild
```

Also try to use -m command in addition to pip install, it provides root access to python command prompt.

```
C:\ python3 -m pip install dmgbuild
```

In case neither of the methods above works for you, check if your python interpreter is already added the `PATH` variable.